# magento local setup issue

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.4

i am trying to setup magento site in my local windows 10 system. i was downloaded the entire content and database from LINUX server into my local. when try to open admin URL link getting below issue. Please suggest.

```
a:4:{i:0;s:42:"Invalid response: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request";i:1;s:1322:"#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\live\lib\Credis\Client.php(538): Credis_Client->read_reply('select')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\live\lib\Credis\Client.php(440): Credis_Client->__call('select', Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\live\lib\Cm\Cache\Backend\Redis.php(117): Credis_Client->select(0)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\live\lib\Zend\Cache.php(153): Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis->__construct(Array)
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\live\lib\Zend\Cache.php(94): Zend_Cache::_makeBackend('Mage_Cache_Back...', Array, true, true)
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\live\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Cache.php(137): Zend_Cache::factory('Varien_Cache_Co...', 'Mage_Cache_Back...', Array, Array, true, true, true)
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\live\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php(1354): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->__construct(Array)
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\live\app\Mage.php(463): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('core/cache', Array)
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\live\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(401): Mage::getModel('core/cache', Array)
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\live\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(295): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initCache(Array)
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\live\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(337): Mage_Core_Model_App->baseInit(Array)
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\live\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\live\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#13 {main}";s:3:"url";s:21:"/live/index.php/admin";s:11:"script_name";s:15:"/live/index.php";}
```

Comment: Check your PHP version.

Answer (score 0):

Comment the cache section from your `app/etc/local.xml` file. The cache section will be as below.

```
<cache>
          <backend>CACHE_BACKEND_CLASS_NAME</backend>
          <backend_options>
            <server>127.0.0.1</server>              <!-- or absolute path to unix socket -->
            <port>6379</port>
            <persistent></persistent>               <!-- Specify a unique string like "cache-db0" to enable persistent connections. -->
            <database>0</database>
            <password></password>
            <force_standalone>0</force_standalone>  <!-- 0 for phpredis, 1 for standalone PHP -->
            <connect_retries>1</connect_retries>    <!-- Reduces errors due to random connection failures -->
            <read_timeout>10</read_timeout>         <!-- Set read timeout duration -->
            <automatic_cleaning_factor>0</automatic_cleaning_factor> <!-- Disabled by default -->
            <compress_data>1</compress_data>        <!-- 0-9 for compression level, recommended: 0 or 1 -->
            <compress_tags>1</compress_tags>        <!-- 0-9 for compression level, recommended: 0 or 1 -->
            <compress_threshold>20480</compress_threshold>  <!-- Strings below this size will not be compressed -->
            <compression_lib>gzip</compression_lib> <!-- Supports gzip, lzf and snappy -->
          </backend_options>
        </cache>
```

It is trying to connect to the cache server which is mentioned in `local.xml` file. I think you took code of production setup and trying to setup in local environment. As you don't have cache in your local setup, it is unable to find the related details. Comment the cache section and clear the `var` folder. Then it is done.